# Images from form post are not being uploaded PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, iis

Trying to use form post with images for the first time and I'm getting stuck. The issue is the images are not making there way to the upload directory after submitting the form.

**Dev Environment**
I'm currently running this with localhost on my windows 8 home edition laptop using IIS & PHP.

Basically I have my form below (*please note this is a cut down version*):

```
<form name="myform" action="includes/processpost.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input id='id_pic' name="upfile1[]" type="file" tabindex="1" multiple accept='image/*' />
<button type="submit" tabindex='2' id="submit_button" >Post</button>
```

Then (using the magic that is google) I've found that I should be able to access the image uploads through using:

```
function confirm_images_valid(){
    $files=array();
    $fdata=$_FILES['upfile1'];
    for($i=0;$i<count($fdata['name']);++$i){
        $files[]=array(
         'name'    =>$fdata['name'][$i],
         'type'  => $fdata['type'][$i],
         'tmp_name'=>$fdata['tmp_name'][$i],
         'error' => $fdata['error'][$i], 
         'size'  => $fdata['size'][$i]  
        );
    }

    echo 'leaving';
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $name = $file['name'];
        $tmp = $file['tmp_name'];
        $des = 'C:\Users\D\Desktop\test\\' . $name;

        if (@move_uploaded_file($tmp, $des)) {
            echo 'working';
        }
        else
        { echo 'bugger';}
    }
}
```

I have also set security on upload_testing folder for 'everyone' to have full privileges, but still I haven't got any files in this folder.

I've modified the following within php.ini (and restarted IIS after each):

```
upload_tmp_dir='C:\upload_testing'
upload_max_filesize=20M
max_execution_time=600
```

Looking for some advice now rather than reading small extracts of how to's and changing more settings!

Thank you in advance

Comment: You haven't bothered checking the `['error']` parameter in $_FILES. Never assume an upload succeeded. Always assume failure and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Comment: I added a echo $file['error'] and it returns 0 ... point taken though I'll make sure I check for errors!

Answer (score 0):

Probably the user executing the webserver has no privileges to write to your User directory. Do you check your temp folder? Probably you don't even have the right to put something there. Do those directories exist? Those are my most common mistakes.

Comment: the IIS user is set to Anon and the directories exist and both have the security user 'everyone' with full permissions set.
I don't know how to extend Anon privileges more than that